# Spring boot asking to add bean even when present

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, derby

I have created a repository class to be used in the Spring Boot application which is defined as:

```
package com.saurav.topic;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository<Topic, String> {
}
```

and the object of this class is used in part of code:

```
@Service
public class TopicService {

    @Autowired
    private TopicRepository topicRepository;
```

but on running the project the error shown is:

> Description:
>
> Field topicRepository in com.saurav.topic.TopicService required a bean of type 'com.saurav.topic.TopicRepository' that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.saurav.topic.TopicRepository' in your configuration.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Its already defined in com.saurav.topic package still it shows error. What to do?

Comment: added following code it helped :
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.saurav"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.saurav")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.saurav" })
@EntityScan("com.saurav")

Comment: By default, spring boot scans any packages that are under the location of your main class. So if your main class is under com.saurav then it should create a TopicRepository bean. What package is your main class under?

Comment: com.saurav.application

Comment: in this case spring boot will scan any packages under com.saurav.application for classes marked with @Component/@Service/@Repository and initialise those beans. As TopicRepository is under com.saurav.topic, it won't be picked up by the default component scan configuration. You can resolve this by override the component scan config with @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.saurav"})

Answer (score 0):

I think in your repository interface the annotation mentioned was `@service` that's wrong so please change it to `@Repository`.
This may works..!